# how to pass details to multiple form without saving it on database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 Applicant Registration Form and each form contain a `insert Query` to insert some Details into Data Base. When an Applicant Fill his 1'st form and click on submit button then his information is insert into data base and here one Registration ID is Generated for those Applicant and jump into 2nd form same process happen in 2nd form then jump into 3rd form and finally at 3rd form applicant get his registration ID.

But here I want these all insert query is run on 3rd form means until a applicant does not reach at 3rd form no any details is insert into database and when he reach at 3rd form then here all the insert query should be run.

But I am able to understand how can I pass the data of 1st form to 2nd form and then to 3rd form. Because here lot of details available at form 1st and 2nd.

Please help me I'm working on a live project and I'm using C# Asp.net.

Comment: you should use view to show different form

Comment: how many tables you used to save values

Comment: At 1st and 2nd form i used 2 Tables and at 3rd form I only show the message to applicant

Comment: Use Tab control for register,at second form u can place submit button..

Comment: As an option, You can save temporary data to `Session` collection if you do not want to save data in database before the last step. Also, if you are using MVC application, you can pass data between actions using model classes instances or `TempData` collection. Are you using WebForms or MVC application?

Comment: Well, sorry, web forms is not my thing. But I suggest there is `Session` collection so you can try to use it. Do smthing like `button_click(formCollection){ Session["temp"] = tb.Text; ... }`

Answer (score 1):

the simplest approach is to use only one form with multiple views.

you can use asp.net multiview control or 3 HTML divs as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not very good in WebForms, but here's a simple walk through about how to pass data between web forms (There's possible simpler and better way):

**Step 1.aspx**  *You enter first number and raise it to power 2 on button click,
                 save result to session and redirect to step 2*

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
</form>


public partial class Step1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {  }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var n = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        Session["temp"] = n * n;
        Response.Redirect("Step2.aspx");
    }
}
```

**Step 2.aspx**: *Display result from form 1, multiply it by new entered number,
             save result to session and redirect to step 3*

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> 
        * 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
</form>

public partial class Step2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int? firstValue;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstValue = (Session["temp"] as int?);
        Label1.Text = firstValue.ToString();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var multiplicator = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        var result = firstValue*multiplicator;
        Session["result"] = result;
        Response.Redirect("Step3.aspx");
    }
}
```

**Step 3.aspx**: *Display result from form 2*

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Result is <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>

public partial class Step3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var res = (Session["result"] as int?);
        Label1.Text = res.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cant you use the same page for all the 3 forms?
Try using panel to display one form at a time and hide the other two
so the values of the textbox will remain as it is
Like on page load only 1 form is displayed. then when you submit, dont clear the values of textboxes but just hide the previous panel and then after submitting 2nf form display 3rd from and then pass insert query with the values of all textboxes and add all data at once to database
Try out